# Correlation between political power and completion of a politician's "grand headquarters"?

Tags: political-theory, history, power

**Introduction:**

In "Parkinson's Law, and Other Studies in Administration", in the "Plans and Plants, or The Administration Block" chapter, Cyril Northcote Parkinson elaborates that organizations have entered the phase of decay when they come to complete their perfect headquarters.

(Actual quote: "Perfection of planning is a symptom of decay. During a period of exciting discovery or progress, there is no time to plan the perfect headquarters.")

He supports his view with examples of the years of completion of various administrative buildings and the the state of development of the respective organizations for the same period of time.

(An excerpt: "The decline of British imperialism actually began with the general election of 1906 and the victory on that occasion of liberal and semi-socialist ideas. It need surprise no one, therefore, to observe that 1906 is the date of completion carved in imperishable granite over the British War Office doors. The campaign of Waterloo might have been directed from poky offices around the Horse Guards Parade. It was, by contrast, in surroundings of dignity that were approved the plans for attacking the Dardanelles.")

While his research is not a scientific proof per se, I think it provides enough substance to consider his point worth of further examination, so as to formulate a scientific hypothesis, at least.

I am particularly interested in historical examples about the rise/ decline in power of specific political entities (political leaders/ political organizations/ political regimes/ political ideologies) and the completion of their "perfect headquarters".

**A specific case study**

One specific example is even more interesting to me, albeit it is not historical one, as it is not complete yet - the reign of Recep Tayyip Erdogan.

Recep Erdogan completed his "perfect palace" - The [Presidential Complex](https://www.npr.org/sections/parallels/2014/12/24/370931835/turkeys-president-and-his-1-100-room-white-palace) in Ankara. This is one of the most remarkable buildings of this kind ever built, in terms of its scale. Can we say that Erdogan's power is in decline, though? Despite the attempted coup and ongoing economic issues, he does not seem to be in any serious decline of power, especially on the geopolitical scene. Or am I wrong?

**Question:**

Could you point historical examples about the years of completion of "perfect headquarters" of political entities (political leaders/ political organizations/ political regimes/ political ideologies) and their state of political development (e.g. rise/ blossom/ decline/ demise) for the same period of time?

Comment: Are you aware that "Parkinson's Law" is meant to be funny?

Comment: @ James K - it is deemed as such. What it was meant to be, only the deceased Cyril Parkinson had been aware of. I think there was a corresponding principle in economics, that people would use a resource as much as they have access to it. In all cases, the specific concept in question, that one about perfect building plans and organizational decay, has been supported by fairly objective historical analysis by Parkinson. His way of writing was humorist, but his concepts have hardly been refuted as mere fun.

Comment: I suspect that this can't be answered as it requires fortune-telling. It is easy to find examples of countries that build their grand palaces before reaching a peak in power/prosperity.  The USA built the Whitehouse and the Capitol building in the first half of the 19th century, when the USA was a regional power and less influential on the global stage than Britain or France.  It is only after the completion of these "perfect headquarters" did the USA become a global superpower.

Comment: [Apple is doomed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Park#/media/File:Apple_park_cupertino_2019.jpg) and I'm not sure if the question is very useful. His power may be constant and any signs of decline might only be small variations. Is the purpose to predict the future or to learn something else how politics works? Maybe simply ask if Parkinson's law helds up for some example autocrats in the past and then we can compare their headquarters perfections with their power and correlate both.

Comment: That said, Erdogan has a plurality, but not majority support in opinion polls. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opinion_polling_for_the_2023_Turkish_presidential_election

Comment: @Trilarion - I am not asking about  a prediction about Erdogan's power from now on, I am asking for an analysis of his power since 2014 to the current day.

Comment: @Trilarion - I have been thinking about the Apple's new headquarters a lot. First of all, what Cyril Parkinson describes is not an organization dying after the erection of its perfect headquarters, but rather having reached its prime and continuing in decline. Back to Apple again, compare it's glorious days of innovation with its current state of mediocrity. I can remember what it used to be using a Mac back in the days of Win 3.1. It was a difference of whole evolutionary phases. What is Apple's innovation today? The next model of  Iphone? That is pathetic.

Comment: @Trilarion - "Maybe simply ask if Parkinson's law helds up for some example autocrats in the past and then we can compare their headquarters perfections with their power and correlate both." - I agree with this one. I chose Erdogan in particular, because the scale of his palace is remarkable. But I agree, a question asking for example from completed historical events would be more useful.

Comment: "What is Apple's innovation today? The next model of Iphone?" This is digressing a bit, but even though Apple's innovation is now more incremental, it still adds up. Just compare modern Iphones and Macbooks with past ones.

Comment: How do you tell that a building is the final, complete HQ, and they won't subsequently build a new, bigger one? It's impossible to answer present cases and past cases are problematic because nobody builds an HQ after they're dead, so by definition your final HQ will be built before you die or lose power.

Comment: @ Stuart F - past cases refer to the HQ built within the political entity's lifetime. Cyril Parkinson does not speak of final HQ. He speaks about either "on the go" HQ (e.g. "poky offices around the Horse Guards Parade" as mentioned in the quote) or "perfectly planned" HQ, which were definitely built with an entity's lifetime (e.g. the British War Office from the same quote).

Comment: Btw, I've also wondered if his concept was true, would it apply to individuals and their personal homes? E.g. decline in a marriage, once the perfectly planned home is built?

Answer (score 2):

Dedicated palace building sometimes means that a specific monarch is distracted from important matters and lets them slip. Which may lead to a coup such as with [Paul I of Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_I_of_Russia#Assassination) and his [Castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Michael%27s_Castle), or other troubles.

However, this does not seem to be the case with Erdogan. He is active in Azerbaijan-Armenia conflict, Syria, and later in the Russia-Ukraine-Turkey triangle. Which means that in his case, building a palace is coincidental.

Answer (score 0):

The observation is only half true.

> During a period of exciting discovery or progress, there is no time to
> plan the perfect headquarters.

True.

For example, in the most turbulent parts of early U.S. history, there were temporary capital cities and federal government offices before a permanent one was established in Washington D.C.

> Perfection of planning is a symptom of decay.

False.

An absence of exciting discovery or progress is not synonymous with decay. An organization can peak and stay there in a steady state that is neither progressing nor declining, or can progress incrementally, for a very long time.

Most of the key edifices in Washington D.C. were built before the United States was a global superpower. The Vatican was built centuries before anyone could reasonably claim that the Roman Catholic Church was in a state of decay. The Great Palaces of France were build long before the French Revolution and held fast for a long time. Many of the colleges in Oxford, England have buildings that are many centuries old, but Oxford University is not in decline.

Comment: @ ohwilleke - I think that if anyone cared to take Cyril Parkinson's concept seriously and develop it further, they'd need to come with a clear definition of "decline". Parkinson only gives (cherry-picked?) examples in his book. My understanding is that, once the perfectly planned HQ is built, the entity in question has reached its zenith. The time period from zenith to visible decline, to actual decay, could be very long. With this point, I think that the examples you mention, seem to fit Parkinson's statement - maybe with the exception of Washington D.C.

Comment: @ ohwilleke - "During a period of exciting discovery or progress, there is no time to plan the perfect headquarters. - True." If that statement is valid, the question which follows is, how did the Americans managed to both plan their perfect headquarters and appear as a world superpower?

Comment: @drabsv The U.S. had reached the point of making boring/incremental progress and discoveries.